# Azure B2C user flow without an email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a scenario where we need to integrate Azure B2C with one of our existing system, where the email is not a mandatory user field, we have only the mobile number of the user as a mandatory field. I am looking for ways to integrate azure B2C where i can give a username and an initial password for the first time, instead of email. And all the password reset scenarios will have to go through OTP or email, where it will be a users choice to give email to reset the password.

> We are able to create the user through Graph API initially, but
>   **stuck** with creating a user-flow where it will ask the username and password instead of email and password.

Comment: have you managed to implement this scenario?

Comment: @PrathapG Not yet implemented hopefully we will do in coming months

Comment: @JustinMathew how did you resolve this topic? I have the same scenario with users that doesn't have an email and they need to use the "password reset flow" without an email

Comment: @Sergio I had to leave my previous company and never got a change to implement it.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose Username as local account types when configuring identity providers for Azure AD B2C in the Azure portal. In your Azure AD B2C tenant, select **Identity providers**, select **Local account**, and then select **Username**.

[image]

Then you need to select **Local Account** again in your user flow.

[image]